# Problems with vue router (history mode) in development server Vue.js - “Cannot GET /config”

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, webpack-dev-server, vue-router

I just wanted to setup my vue project with the [full webpack template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack), use vue router and link different urls to different components.

The ***src/router/index.html*** is the following:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import Home from '../pages/home.vue';
// eslint-disable-next-line
import Config from '../pages/config.vue';

Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
  mode: 'hash',
  routes: [
    { path: '/', component: Home },
    { path: '/config', component: Config },
  ],
});
```

When I run ***npm run dev*** and access the above routes, I have the following output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Up to here, everything is working fine. The problem is when I use the ***history mode***, I can’t access to localhost:8080/config:

[image]

And the console doesn’t show any error:

[image]

Another thing I tried was switching the mode to history using the simple-webpack template. The worst part is that it worked! So, the problem is in the webpack-template, but I don't know how to make this work.

I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: Looks like there were some changes in the webpack template related to the `historyApiFallback` option used by history mode ([GitHub commit](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/commit/77f818fa7e1cad836d5d89164c2c93bccc4a5b96)).
Try creating a new project so it uses the latest version of the template. It could still be broken, though, so you may have to change that line to `historyApiFallback: true` manually.

Comment: I did what yurir636 said: just change the historyApiFallback to true in the webpack.dev.conf.js file, and that solved the problem.

Comment: I got a blank page when using route with params