# Vue.js + Node.js: Where is Server Config

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vue-router

(note: total scrub with coding here, so please understand if I say something silly.)

I started a Vue.js project with the typical [webpack](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/tree/develop/template) template, for making a single-page application. (I have not modified the document structure from this.) There are no other frameworks on top.

To get rid of the hash in the URL, the doc talks about turning on [history mode](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html). After specifying so, however, you must configure the server. To quote;

> [...] add a simple catch-all fallback route to your server. If the URL doesn't match any static assets, it should serve the same index.html page that your app lives in.

Since I'm using Node.js + Vue.js with nothing else added on top, this should be the corresponding example of the server configuration.

```
const http = require('http')
const fs = require('fs')
const httpPort = 80

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile('index.htm', 'utf-8', (err, content) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log('We cannot open "index.htm" file.')
    }

    res.writeHead(200, {
      'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8'
    })

    res.end(content)
  })
}).listen(httpPort, () => {
  console.log('Server listening on: http://localhost:%s', httpPort)
})
```

However, I cannot for the life of me figure out where this is supposed to go, because it doesn't specify such. Does this go into main.js? The Router's index.js? Or is it a part of one of the things in the build folder, or config? (And would there be any difference were I to run a production version, say, on heroku?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webpack template comes with a `webpack-dev-server` (Node.js based) already prepared for the history mode: there is no need to edit any config while you are **developing** your app via `npm run dev`.

You have to apply the server configuration shown in the docs when you are **deploying** your app via `npm run build`, that will create a `/dist` folder which content you are free to upload to any static server (not necessarily Node.js).

The example code is the main script of a Node.js server, but it's pretty much bare-bones, it returns the content of `index.html` (there is also a "typo" in the code, should be `.html` not `.html`) to any request, but that breaks any other asset requests like CSS or JS. It's for demostrative purposes only: respond to any route (URL) with `index.html`.

If you plan to deploy into a Node.js server you should look for a better script.

Comment: The rest makes sense, but I'm not sure the first part is correct-- Vue router paths have always come with a `/#/` attached to them even when I'm running `npm run dev`, even when I ran the unmodified template.

Comment: @cabbage have you changed the `mode: 'history'` part in the router file? I understood so in your post. | In my answer with "configuration" I meant the server configuration (edited now). The mode is client configuration.

Comment: Yes, I added the `mode: 'history'` to the router (which technically works; if I run the project, the `/#/` no longer shows, but as soon as I attempt to navigate it says it can't get the page.

I just realized this, but does it have to do with the `build.js` file coming in the production node environment? Or is that irrelevant since `npm run dev` runs with the dev webpack configuration...

Comment: (Awful wording so I deleted previous comment;) How do I fix the issue of navigating directly causing errors, then? (EG: if I navigate to /users/1, it spits errors, even though I have `mode: 'history'` applied)

Comment: @cabbage Not sure. Been trying to replicate it with a fresh webpack template, and it works fine. | Just remembered this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068084/problems-with-vue-router-history-mode-in-development-server-vue-js-cannot-g check your `/build/webpack.dev.conf.js` file and compare the `historyApiFallback` part with the latest https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/blob/develop/template/build/webpack.dev.conf.js