# Vue router and webpack - history mode config localhost

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, vue-router, vue-cli

Basically, I'm using Vue cli with webpack template and I need to use history mode in vue router, but i'm using params for a route.

I read this doc: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html
and I look this thread too: [Problems with vue router (history mode) in development server Vue.js - “Cannot GET /config”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48068084/problems-with-vue-router-history-mode-in-development-server-vue-js-cannot-g)

So I change webpack.dev.conf.js from:

```
historyApiFallback: {
      rewrites: [
        { from: /.*/, to: path.posix.join(config.dev.assetsPublicPath, 'index.html') },
      ],
    }
```

to

```
historyApiFallback: true
```

Now I get a blank page when tried to access a page with params. Any clue?

Comment: Are you using `server-side` rendering? Can you post code to reproduce the issue? I recently created a small app using Vue and was able to access pages with params also.

Comment: With history mode? No, its just client side.

Comment: Yes, with history mode. I used `2.5.x` or greater version of `Vue`

Comment: Everything is updated here. This is the route and it was working before history mode:
    {
      path: '/partner/:id',
      name: 'PartnerDetail',
      component: PartnerDetail
   }

Comment: You didn't change webpack? Because with history mode, usually you need to config server stuff as well development config

Comment: No i did not change the config

Comment: Can you share your historyApiFallback config and route example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165408/discussion-between-a1626-and-joao-saro).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

I exposed this question in Vue Forum and @LinusBorg help me to understand what happens with vue-router and history mode:

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vue-router-and-webpack-history-mode-config-localhost/27880/12

Basically, he recommends to "should not have to change anything (I [LinusBorg] maintain this template)" on webpack/config files. As I changed to relative paths, it broken.

As I need it to deliver the project to a sub-folder, he recommends fews steps:

> 1. history mode can’t really work without absolute paths. Releative paths to aset files will break when you visit a subroute directly.
>      That’s not something you will be able to work around.
> 2. If you want to serve from a subfolder, you have to let the router know about that by setting the base1 option.
> 3. you also have set write subfolder as the assetsPublicPath in the config (for both build and dev, unless you make the router’s base
>      switch according to environment).

Then, the page with params stills broken, because the server (and even localhost) need to be config as documented here: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/history-mode.html